# jQuery star rating plugin variable doesnt return correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-bar-rating

I'm making a rating system to rate a movie using 5 stars. I use the `jQuery bar plugin` for this ([jQuery bar plugin](http://antenna.io/demo/jquery-bar-rating/examples/)).

Someone can vote from 1 to 5. The data is stored in the database. After someone votes the stars will be disabled and show the amount of stars the user rated.

With the `initialRating` value of the plugin it will define how many stars are 'selected'. So if this variable is 4, 4 stars will be colored.

When I hard code for example `initialRating: 4` it works. Although when I use `initialRating: currentRating` (the voted amount of stars) it won't return the right amount and it will just show 1 star. When I `console.log` `currentRating` it will return `4`.

So how does it come that hardcoding `4` works, instead of `currentRating` (with the value of 4) which doesn't work.

**Code**

```
$(function () {

    currentRating = $(".rating").val(); //Getting the value that someone vote previously
    console.log(currentRating); // Displays 4

    $('#rating').barrating('show', {
        theme: 'fontawesome-stars',
        showSelectedRating: true,
        initialRating: currentRating,
        onSelect: function (value, text) {
            movieTitle = $('.movie-name'). text(),
               tmdb_id = $(".imdb_id").val(),
                _token = $(".csrf_field").val();

            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': _token
                },
                method: "POST",
                url: "/movies/" + tmdb_id + "/rate",
                data: {
                    title: movieTitle,
                    tmdb_id: tmdb_id,
                    rating: value
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#div1").html(result);
                }
            });
        } 
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: can you add a fiddle with a simpler version of the code?

Comment: Found the problem, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `currentRating` is a `string` whereas the plug-in is expecting a `integer`.

Converting the `string` into an `integer` using `parseInt()` will solve the problem.

**Code**

`currentRating = parseInt(currentRating);`

Comment: Let's just hope your "currentRating" string doesn't start with "0", eg "010" = 8...  always use `parseInt(currentRating, 10);` (though seems later browsers don't have this foible)